# Output vector of vector to text file with tab delimiter C++

Tags: c++, text, vector, output

i'm trying to output a 2D vector into a txt file, the problem is that i'm getting extra tabs at row end and new line at the of the text 
here it is my code

```
 int main()
{

    vector< vector<double> > mv;
    vector< vector<double> >::iterator row;
    vector<double>::iterator col;
    ofstream output_file("Mat.txt");
    setVector(mv,5,5);
    for(row = mv.begin(); row != mv.end();row++)
    {
        for(col = row->begin();col != row->end();col++)
        {
            output_file << *col << '\t';
        }
       output_file << '\n';
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Output Sample:
[image]

Comment: of course... you are putting a \t after the last element of the row!

Comment: so what do you suggest to do ?

Comment: quick and dirty: loop untill row->end() -1 and then after the loop just output the last

Comment: I'm pretty sure branching on a condition (like "is this the last/first element in a row/vector") is covered before looping in any decent tutorial. You can do such things inside the loop body, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write

```
for(row = mv.begin(); row != mv.end();row++)
{
    if(row != mv.begin()) {
         output_file << '\n';
    }
    for(col = row->begin();col != row->end();col++)
    {
        if(col != row->begin) {
            output_file << '\t';
        }
        output_file << *col;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of solving the problem:

1. Check if you're printing the last element, and don't print the tab/newline.
2. Check if you're printing the first element, and if not print a *leading* tab/newline.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange our code so that `row` is in the inner loop and `col` in the outer loop. If you naming conventions make sense, that would be a big step toward fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
for ( row = mv.begin(); row != mv.end(); ++row )
{
    std::string outs;
    for ( col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col )
    {
        outs += *col;
        outs += '\t';
    }
    outs[outs.length() - 1] = '\n';
    output_file << outs;
}
```